# synonymize taste and flavor tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[flavor](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flavor) and [taste](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/taste) are actual synonyms already and their  use in questions seems to be fairly similar to requests for a beverage that meets a flavor profile to asking how serving in X or doing Y would affect taste.

Comment: Are you suggesting to merge these two tags together ?

Comment: As I understand it making tags synonym is one discrete step and actually merging the tags is a separate discrete action that can be done after they are made synonyms. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work

Comment: so you would like taste to be a synonym of flavor and flavor to be synonym of taste ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am proposing, based on how both seem to be used to talk about the exact same thing currently, eventually we could merge them.

Comment: haha got you :) that sound fair to me they are very similar tags

Comment: They are not currently synonyms in the SE sense.  (But "flavor" has a synonym, "flavour".)  To bring these together as one tag with a synonym, we'll need to decide which is the primary -- the tag name that actually shows up on questions.

Comment: Merging and synonymizing these tags seems sensible, especially given that the tag wiki for [taste] says: "Questions about flavor and how it is influenced by various factors such as temperature and glassware."

Comment: @V2Blast long time no see! Nice to see you over here in addition to RPG.SE!

Comment: @JoshuaAslanSmith: Hello! Since I became a CM, I've been poking my head around the network :)